# How can I add the server name to the subject line of a SSIS subscription email?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssis, etl, ssis-2008

In Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) RDL report files uploaded are often set with the ability to send out periodic email alerts.  On the SSIS 2008 system, this is called "Subscriptions".  When a new email alert is set up, there are system defined strings in the Subject line which is presented as default as:

```
@ReportName was executed at @ExecutionTime
```

How can I add a new item to this subject line for the server name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `@ReportServerUrl` to get the reporting Server in RDL files as Hadi mentioned. But for the subscription subject line itself, SSRS only allows for two variables, `@ReportName` and `@ExecutionTime`.

**References**

- [Format File Name in EMAIL Data Driven Subscription](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e766789b-c87f-43fc-ba35-f72080776561/format-file-name-in-email-data-driven-subscription?forum=sqlreportingservices)
- [e-mail subscription + variables](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/ced9cb0b-6bc1-43e3-948c-04ea85f2b2b8/email-subscription-variables?forum=sqlreportingservices)

Comment: This is weird. Is there any documentation mentionnig that?

Answer (score 2):

In SSIS, You can use `@MachineName` system variable which return the server name.

For additional informaion check the following link:

- [SSIS system variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/system-variables?view=sql-server-2017)

---

In SSRS, you can yse `@ReportServerUrl` variable.

For more info check the following link:

- [Built-in Collections - Built-in Globals and Users References (Report Builder)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/built-in-collections-built-in-globals-and-users-references-report-builder?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Hadi, those are variables that appear in the RDL, not in the subscription subject line.  In the subscription subject line, you are only allowed two variables: the Report Name and the Time that Time that the report ran.